# adding element in array using array_push( ) in php

Tags: php, arrays

adding element in array using array_push( ) in php

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($d); $i++){
    $ins_data[$i]=$this->input->post('question_type_rt_'.$i.'');
    $a=array();
    array_push($a,$ins_data[$i]);
    print_r($a);
    echo"<br>";
}
```

where it gives output

```
Array ( [0] => 1 )
Array ( [0] => 2 )
Array ( [0] => 1 )
Array ( [0] => 2 )
Array ( [0] => 1 )
```

but i want all element in same array

and create string from that array

like `12121`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array needs to be initialised outside of the for loop to prevent overwriting the reference to it each time you run through the for loop:

```
$a=array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($d); $i++){
  $ins_data[$i]=$this->input->post('question_type_rt_'.$i.'');
  array_push($a,$ins_data[$i]);
}
print_r($a);
```